# Nested Loops to make shapes

Tags: java, nested

I am having a little trouble with one shape I am currently trying to make here is my code currently:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Problem2
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      int n = 0;

      do
      {
         System.out.print("Enter an odd integer greater than or equal to 5: ");
         n = input.nextInt();

      }while(n < 5 || n % 2 == 0);

      boxWithMinorDiagonal(n);

      rightTriangle(n);

      printNLetter(n);

      fancySquare(n);

   }


   public static void fancySquare(int n)
   {
      System.out.println();

      int tempRow = 2;
      int tempCol = 2;
      int tempColDec = n - 2;
      int tempRowInc = 2;

      for(int row = 1; row <= n; row++)
      {
         for(int col = 1; col <= n; col++)
         {
            if(row == 1 || row == n || col == 1 || col == n)
            {
               if(row == 1 && col == 1 || row == 1 && col == n || row == n && col == 1 || row == n && col == n)
               {
                  System.out.print("@");
               }
               else
               {
                  System.out.print("*");
               }
            }

            else if(tempRow == row && tempCol == col)
            {
               System.out.print("+");
               tempCol++;
               tempRow++;
            }

            else
            {
               System.out.print(" ");
            }
            if(row == tempRowInc && col == tempColDec)
            {
               System.out.print("+");
               tempColDec--;
               tempRowInc++;
            }


         }
         System.out.println();
      }
   }
}
```

Everything works correctly except my last method "fancySquare" is not printing out how I would like it to. It is currently printing out this shape if the user input is 9:

```
@*******@
*+     + *
* +   +  *
*  + +   *
*   ++   *
*  +  +  *
* +    + *
*+      +*
@*******@
```

It should look like this instead

```
@*******@
*+     +*
* +   + *
*  + +  *
*   @   *
*  + +  *
* +   + *
*+     +*
@*******@
```

Comment: Please eliminate the code that isn't relevant to your question.

Comment: You seem to be off by 1.  The `<=` would be a good thing to investigate.

Comment: Currently your expected output has an odd number of characters.  What would the output look like with an even number?

Comment: Can only use odd numbers

Answer (score 0):

Try to use named booleans for your checks to make it more understandable.
More common is to use zero based index, but i stick to your version to make it more similar and easier to match for you.

```
public static void fancySquare(int n) {
    System.out.println();

    for (int row = 1; row <= n; row++) {
        for (int col = 1; col <= n; col++) {

            final boolean firstRow = row == 1;
            final boolean lastRow = row == n;
            final boolean firstCol = col == 1;
            final boolean lastCol = col == n;

            // calc the center
            final boolean center = row == (n + 1) / 2 && col == (n + 1) / 2;
            // calc the marker
            final boolean marker = row == col || n - row + 1 == col;

            // we need the @ marker at the corners (1,1) || (1,n) || (n,1) || (n,n)
            if ((firstRow || lastRow) && (firstCol || lastCol)) {
                System.out.print("@");
            // we need the * in the first & last column/row which is no corner
            } else if (firstRow || lastRow || firstCol || lastCol) {
                System.out.print("*");
            // we need a @ also in the center
            } else if (center) {
                System.out.print("@");
            // we need the plus on the diagonals
            } else if (marker) {
                System.out.print("+");
            // instead we need a space
            } else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting, I am gonna try to use some of your code snippet here thanks!

Comment: can you explain to me on how the boolean marker statement works exactly.

Comment: the marker has to be set on the "cross" between the current row and the current column  this from the left side (row == col) and the other way around from the right side is the current width - the row. this also considers the first and last row but that case is captured by the first if statement so i dont have to take care about for the marker